# icu4j-2.6.1.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=40 poolCount = 47

Tags: java

Recently I am working in a migration project where the existing application is required to be upgraded from **JBOSS5** to **JBOSS7**

When I am deploying the existing wars into the new **JBOSS7** server, I am getting the below WARNING.

> 016-06-07 12:21:05,841 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC
>   service thread 1-4) JBAS015852: Could not index class
>   com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class at
>   /../../WEB-INF/lib/icu4j-2.6.1.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Unknown tag! pos=40 poolCount = 47.

I am suppose to remove all these type of WARNINGs. Please do suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found one solution.

Looks like icu4j-2.6.1.jar is not compatible with the JBOSS7.

So I have changed the version and I am now using the icu4j-4.8.1.jar instead of the previous one. Now I can not see the WARNING.